# Deploy SQL File from VSS to SQL Server using Batch File

Tags: powershell, stored-procedures, batch-file, visual-sourcesafe

I want to know if there is any way for me to deploy a stored procedure (sql file) that is checked-in at VSS? I have a couple of procedures that I want to deploy to SQL Server. I'm trying to create a batch file to deploy them from VSS to SQL Server.

I want to achieve this since we would like to remove direct access to SQL Server. So that everything step we do on the procedures could be monitored.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I have also read that it's possible in Powershell. If anyone can point me to a good way to do it, that would be appreciated so much! I'm new to the VSS, Batch Files, and Powershells. So I'm a little bit confused where to start. Thanks!

This is what I have so far. But it doesn't work.

```
@echo off
cls

set path=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe
set ssdir=\\MySampel_VSS\VSS\SampleDB
set Recursive = Yes

set /p SName=Server Name :
set /p UName=User Name :
set /p Pwd=Password :
set /p DbName=Database Name :

set /p choice=ARE YOU SURE TO EXECUTE SCRIPTS in %DbName% (y/n) ?

if '%choice%'=='y' goto begin
goto end

:begin
if exist C:\Scripts\error.txt del C:\Scripts\error.txt

@echo on

sqlcmd -S %SName% -U %UName% -P %Pwd% -d %DbName% -I -i $/Database/SampleDB/Procedures/MySample.sql >> error.txt 2>&1

@notepad error.txt

:end
```

Comment: Do you want a batch file or a PowerShell script? You've tagged both, but specifically mentioned batch in the question.

Comment: and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: sorry. that's a mistake. i want to create a batch-file. thanks! :)

Comment: @Endoro i have tried playing around with a script I have that's for pinning files on VSS. I don't have prior experience to this kind of stuff so i'm basically relying on what I find on google and what I have. :( Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Visual Source Safe command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh58tzy9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in a batch file to deploy a project that is checked in. Take a look at the Checkout and Deploy commands in particular.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! Will this deploy my StoredProcedure file into the Database? Because the process I want to achieve is: 1. Checkin .sql SP to VSS. 2. Create batch file to deploy .sql SP from VSS to SQL Server. 3. Check if SP exists in SQL Server. Thanks!